# Ruby On Rails: ElasticSearch authentication (Tire and ElasticSearch-rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, tire

I have a Ruby On Rails app deployed on Heroku, Im using the ElasticSearch add-on, my elastic search clusters were working normally but recently ElasticSearch add-on required all clusters to enforce authentication to protect the data that is inside of the hosted cluster, now on every request we try to make we receive the following exception:

```
Tire::Search::SearchRequestFailed (401 : {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"action [indices:data/read/search] requires authentication","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"shield\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"action [indices:data/read/search] requires authentication","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"shield\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}},"status":401}):
```

We configured some users from the [Shield](https://www.elastic.co/products/x-pack/security) plugin that comes with Elasticsearch, however Im not sure how can I enter this authentication from my ruby On Rails application, Im using Tire to integrate elastic search in my Ruby On Rails app, but I can't find were can I put this information in order to authenticate my app and solve this issue.

We would like to know how to authenticate using these two gems:
[ElasticSearch-rails](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails) and [Tire](https://github.com/karmi/retire)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend the use of elasticsearch-rails instead of tire (abbandoned).

With elasticsearch-rails:

**gemfile**

```
gem 'elasticsearch'
gem 'elasticsearch-model'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails'
```

**Do the models searchable**

Apply the [feature extraction pattern](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model#feature-extraction-pattern) (searchable concern) to your models.

**Configure your elastic search client**

for all models in an initializer (`config/initializers/elastic_search_client.rb` or whatever) with auth using common URL format

`Elasticsearch::Client.new url: 'https://username:password@api.server.org:4430/search`'

or with auth using a hash

```
Elasticsearch::Client.new hosts: [
  { host: 'my-protected-host',
    port: '443',
    user: 'USERNAME',
    password: 'PASSWORD',
    scheme: 'https'
  } ]
```

take a look at [advanced client options](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/tree/master/elasticsearch-transport#configuration) for additional information.

Note: I did not test it by myself, this is the theory, maybe something is missing, check the [elasticsearch-rails docs](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, all you need to do is to set environment variable; see my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70392006/3090068

Answer (score 3):

You can set `ELASTICSEARCH_URL` environment variable to `https://USER:PASSWORD@some.domain:9200`.

This works because the client initialized by the `elasticsearch-rails` gem will actually be that of `elastic-transport-ruby` gem, and the client of this gem will use `ELASTICSEARCH_URL` environment variable, as defined in here: https://github.com/elastic/elastic-transport-ruby/blob/1dcb6c9db68dba70958e99d50e35a577d7d7f628/lib/elastic/transport/client.rb#L139-L144